# PHP : file not starting downloading from my server x once after downloading it from remote server

Tags: php

I want to build something like a cache where i download file x once from google drive and after that the file should be served from my own server. but it doesn't work.

**code 1:**

```
require_once "google/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php";

require_once "google/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php";

require_once "google/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php";

require_once "google/vendor/autoload.php";

$DRIVE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'mobileformsafica@appspot.gserviceaccount.com';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'mobileformsafica-0497d13f3902.p12';

function buildService() {//function for first build up service
global $DRIVE_SCOPE, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH;

  $key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
  $auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
      $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      array($DRIVE_SCOPE),
      $key);
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setUseObjects(true);
  $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
  return new Google_DriveService($client);
}
/**
 * Print a file's metadata.
 *
 * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param string $fileId ID of the file to print metadata for.

 */





function printFile($service, $fileId) {
  try {
    $file = $service->files->get($fileId);

    print "Title: " . $file->getTitle();
    print "Description: " . $file->getDescription();
    print "MIME type: " . $file->getMimeType();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}

/**
 * Download a file's content.
 *
 * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param File $file Drive File instance.
 * @return String The file's content if successful, null otherwise.
 */



function downloadFile($service, $file) {
$downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl();
if ($downloadUrl) {
$request = new Google_HttpRequest($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
$httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);
if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {

return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
} else {
// An error occurred.
return null;
}
} else {
// The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
return null;
}
}
try {

//https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9ez4Vc-n0DbWkV6VmtRZFJIbnhqU3d2QmNHTTZfWWJYZGM0
$file_id=$_GET['link'];

$service=buildService();
//printFile($service,$file_id);
$file = $service->files->get($file_id);
$content = downloadFile($service,$file);
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/$file_id","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);


$boa = $file->getTitle();

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$boa");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen((downloadFile($service,$file))));


print(downloadFile($service,$file));



  } catch (Exception $e) {
  print "An error occurred1: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Now i wan to implement this **code 2** below on my **code 1**:

```
class Downloader
{

    private $path;
    public $filename;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->path = dirname(__FILE__);
    }

    public function getFile($url)
    {
        $fileName = $this->getFileName($url);
        if(!file_exists($this->path."/".$fileName)){
            $this->downloadFile($url,$fileName);
        }

        return file_get_contents($this->path."/".$fileName);
    }


    public function getFileName($url)
    {
        $slugs = explode("/", $url);
        $this->filename = $slugs[count($slugs)-1];
        return $this->filename;
    }

    private function downloadFile($url,$fileName)
    {
        //This is the file where we save the information
        $fp = fopen ($this->path.'/'.$fileName, 'w+');
        //Here is the file we are downloading, replace spaces with %20
        $ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
        // write curl response to file
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        // get curl response
        curl_exec($ch); 
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);
    }

}


$downloader = new Downloader();
$content = $downloader->getFile("YOUR URL");

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$downloader->filename.'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . mb_strlen($content));
print $content;
exit;
```

Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.Please help.

Comment: Instead of padding your question with 'please help', clarify 'but it doesn't work'. What is actually happening, are you getting errors, etc?

Comment: @cteski i got 500 error

Comment: Please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve], then edit your question to be more clear (don't just add comments).  Was the 500 error in downloading or later?  What have you tried to debug this?  You can add echo statements to see how far the code got before dying, and can set flags to show errors.  Search here on "PHP show errors."

Comment: @kaaris please specify the error message you got.. **i got 500** is not enough to provide help