# Download Remote File with PHP to Server and finally output to browser

Tags: php

I want to download a remote file with php, save it and output it  to the user.  I want to buffer files because some users can download the same file at the same time and save bandwidth.

I found a script to download a file from remote server directly:

```
set_time_limit(0);

$url = 'http://example.com/example.zip';
$file = basename($url);

$fp = fopen($file, 'w');

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: Your going to have to cache the file locally for multiple users to see the file.

Comment: @JasonK yeah. but i don't think the code is working...

Answer (score 0):

Here a little snippet.

You check locally if the file exists, if so: you fetch the content and send it to the client.

Otherwise you make the curl request to fetch and store the file content

```
set_time_limit(0);

$url = 'http://example.com/example.zip';

$file = basename($url);
if(!file_exists($file)) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    file_put_contents($file, $data);
}

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: a better version should store files in a dedicated cache directory. And maybe should have a better check to avoid filename collision.

Comment: how implement it with this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668720/php-file-not-starting-downloading-from-my-server-x-once-after-downloading-it-f

Comment: I saw the question, and it's trivial.. you should specify the error message (not only the error code) that you receive from your code